# arm-linux-androideabi-clang: No such file or directory on OSX

Tags: android, c, macos, makefile

Trying to run this script. It is related with OpenConnect API.

```
# Build run_pie helper program
#
$(DESTDIR)/sbin/run_pie: run_pie.c $(TOOLCHAIN_BUILT)
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)/sbin
    $(TRIPLET)-clang $< -o $@ -ldl

.PHONY: run_pie
run_pie: $(DESTDIR)/sbin/run_pie
```

Then i get this error message.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-clang run_pie.c -o 
external/arm/openconnect/android/arm-linux-androideabi/out/sbin/run_pie -ldl

make[1]: arm-linux-androideabi-clang: No such file or directory

make[1]: *** [/external/arm/openconnect/android/arm-linux-androideabi/out/sbin/run_pie] Error 1
```

I think this problem occurs because i am macOS user.

Comment: `arm-linux-androideabi-clang` is a cross compiler. You may have to install a package to get it. But, it looks like you already have a package installed (in `/external/...`) Or, it could be already installed in a special directory and you need to add that directory to `$PATH`. Try `find /external -name arm-linux-androideabi-clang`

Comment: As you mentioned i don't have cross compiler clang. Do you know how can i download it? I already have android ndk and toolchain.

Comment: What did the `find` produce? You may want to start it from `/` But, I found the source and [some] prebuilt versions in the android source repo. See: https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo

Answer (score 2):

vi ~/.bash_profile

and writing

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/macbookpro/Developer/toolchain/bin

is worked for me. You have to adjust the path. According the location of toolchain.

By the way toolchain is related with NDK. So you can create toolchain folder with NDK.